# Find Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

We recently started integrals and I am a little lost, I was wondering if someone can guide me through this problem. I was trying to research more about the topic but I still need help.

Find $\int_{0}^4(3·ƒ (x)−4·g(x))dx$
If $\int_{0}^2 ƒ(x)dx=12$, $\int_{2}^4 ƒ(x)dx=3$, $\int_{0}^6g(x)dx=6$, and $\int_{4}^6g(x)dx=10$

Comment: What rules do you know when dealing with integrals?

Comment: Well I know you sometimes find the antiderivative and 
 $\int_{a}^bf(x)dx=-\int_b^af(x)dx$.

Comment: you will have learned rules having to do with summing integrals going from one set of limits to another, and about multiplying integrands by a constant.  Those will be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules might come in handy:
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)+g(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx+\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$$
$$c*\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} c*f(x) dx$$
$$\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx+\int_{b}^{c}f(x) dx$$

By (1) and (2), Your problem is reduced to $$3\int_{0}^{4} f(x)dx-4\int_{0}^{4} g(x) dx$$
By (3), you can split up the integral into its known parts:
$$3\big[\int_{0}^{2} f(x)dx+\int_{2}^{4} f(x)dx\big]-4\big[\int_{0}^{6}g(x) dx-\int_{4}^{6} g(x) dx\big]$$
By the values given, the integral is reduced to:
$3[12+3]-4[6-10]=45+16=61$

Comment: Thanks, I am little confused because there are only constants, no variable like $x$ to plug anything into

Comment: Edited to include solution.

Comment: how come it is not $3[12+3]-4[6+10]$?

Comment: You get the minus because you are splitting up $\int_{0}^{4} g(x) dx$, and $\int_{0}^{6} g(x) dx=\int_{0}^{4} g(x) dx+\int_{4}^{6} g(x) dx$ Subtracting $\int_{4}^{6}g(x) dx$ from both sides gives the integral, at which point you substitute.

Comment: ahh ok so the answer is $61$ instead of $29$ thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, I simply messed up on putting a + sign instead of a -.

Answer (score 1):

Using linearity we have

$$\int_{0}^4(3f(x)−4g(x))dx=\int_{0}^4 3 f(x)dx−\int_0^44g(x)dx=3\int_{0}^4 f(x)dx−4\int_0^4g(x)dx.$$

Now,

$$\int_{0}^4 f(x)dx=\int_{0}^2f(x)dx+\int_2^4 f(x)dx$$ and

$$\int_{0}^6 g(x)dx=\int_{0}^4g(x)dx+\int_4^6g(x)dx.$$

Substitute all known values and get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

- Integral is linear

$$ \int (af(x)+bg(x))dx = a\int f(x)dx + b \int g(x)dx $$

- Integral is additive, thus

$$ \int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^cf(x)dx + \int_c^bf(x)dx$$

Try this to solve this problem or get the direct answer from answer below, depends on your motivation.